# SQL error while using MySQL geometry function

Tags: mysql, sqlgeography, sqlgeometry

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure1    
AS  
DECLARE @Seedid int, @data1 float, @data2 float, @g geometry  

DECLARE member_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT id from test1 ;  

OPEN member_cursor;  

FETCH NEXT FROM member_cursor  
INTO @Seedid ;  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    select @data1 =data1 from test where id=@Seedid  
    select @data2 =data2 from test where id=@Seedid  
    update test1  
       set data4 = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT (@data1 @data2)', 0)
        where id=@Seedid;  
    -- This is executed as long as the previous fetch succeeds.  
    FETCH NEXT FROM member_cursor  
    INTO @Seedid ;  
END  
RETURN  
CLOSE member_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE member_cursor;
```

**I am getting the following error:**

> The statement has been terminated.  
>   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry":   
>   System.FormatException: 24141: A number is expected at position 13 of the input. The input has @data1.

Answer (score 1):

After some effort, I finally found the solution for this problem. Posting the solution if someone else encounter such problem again. In Geometry when I am passing `@data1` and `@data2`, its those variable as `@data1` only not its **float value**. So, What we can do is following:

```
select @data1 =data1 from test1 where id=@Seedid  
select @data2 =data2 from test1 where id=@Seedid  
Set @POINTSTR = 'POINT(' + CAST(@data1 AS varchar(32)) + ' ' + CAST(@data2 AS varchar(32)) + ')';  
update test1  set data4 = geometry::STGeomFromText(@POINTSTR, 4326) where id=@Seedid;
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I should have realized that I needed to convert the points (floats in my case) to text before passing them into the `...FromText()` function :).